# A question about CABasicAnimation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
- (IBAction) showCurrentTime : (id) sender

{
    NSLog(@" --- showCurrentTime called --- ");

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

    static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;

    if (!formatter) 
    {
        formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setTimeStyle : NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    }

    [timeLabel setText : [formatter stringFromDate : now]]; 

    // Create a basic animation

    CABasicAnimation *spin =
       [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath : @"transform.rotaton"];


    // set transform values
    [spin setFromValue : [NSNumber numberWithFloat : M_PI * 0.0]];
    [spin setToValue   : [NSNumber numberWithFloat : M_PI * 2.0]];
    [spin setDuration  : 1.0];

    // Add animation object to the layer
    [[timeLabel layer] addAnimation : spin
                       forKey       : @"spinAnimation"];

}
```

Consider the above sample code :

The above code sample compiles with absolutely no errors and warnings, but the "timeLabel", which is expected to spin 360 degrees in 1 second does not move at all.  Have checked that the method "showCurrentTime" has indeed been called from the console's NSLog() output.  The above method has been tested on both the phone simulator and the real device. The same problem comes up - everything is ok except no spin ...  Please help.

Comment: have you tried rotating to something other than 360?  It may be seeing that you are ending at the same place you are starting and failing to go through the motion to get there.

Comment: Have tried M_PI * 1.0 but still doesn't move at all ...

Comment: Thanks for your comment, have just tried without the M_PI (in case it is 0), but still no "spin" ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try `[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath : @"transform.rotation"];`

you forgot the "i" in rotation :)

Comment: Thank you for your kind assistance. My spelling needs to be improved or my mind needs to be reset or both ... Thanks!